# compare single field in mysql for multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, select

I Have an array of different ids, I want to iterate this array and use these ids to be compared with a single field in DB Table

Example

```
classid{
0=>1,
1=>2
}
```

and I have table as

```
id name
1   myname
2   ur name
3   everyonename
```

Now how can i retrieve the values for both id=1 and id = 2 in just a Select query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you want is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2)
```

To create this from PHP, you would use something like

```
$classid = array(1, 2);
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (%s)',
               implode(',', $classid));
```

**You should be ultra careful to prevent SQL injections** if the values in `$classid` are coming from an external source! Normally this is achieved with prepared statements and bound parameters, but in this case (where you want to use `IN`) this is not possible AFAIK.

Therefore you should sanitize the values yourself, using something like

```
// This will convert all the values in the array to integers,
// which is more than enough to prevent SQL injections.
$classid = array_map('intval', $classid);
```

Read more about [protecting yourself from SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: very very Thanks for all the details @Jon